# air for android camera

Tags: android, air, camera

As I know there are not many features about camera. I want to connect to camera using Camera class instead of CameraUI. Here are my codes ;

```
var myCam2:Camera = new Camera();
var theVideo:Video = new Video();

myCam2 = Camera.getCamera();
myCam2.setQuality(0, 40);
myCam2.setMode(400,280,2,true);

theVideo.attachCamera(myCam2);
```

My problem is, it works on desktop but it doesn't work on Android. But this will be an Android application so I need to make it work on Android. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

permissions - add to your description file the following:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/></manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

Comment: Hi Danel. Thanks for your answer but my problem was a little more unique. It ended up as an manufacturer error. I tested the codes with different Android Devices other than my first test device, and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Set `<renderMode>direct</renderMode>` in your app.xml, That configuration solve my problem I hope you will